# How to add images in divs randomly using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code. How to set images randomly in 5 divs out of 10 every refresh; images should be set randomly every refresh image and should display different places. I don't understand what JavaScript I have to use.

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="pr-1">1</div>     
   <div id="pr-2">2</div>
   <div id="pr-3">3</div>
   <div id="pr-4">4</div>
   <div id="pr-5">5</div>
   <div id="pr-6">6</div> 
   <div id="pr-7">7</div>
   <div id="pr-8">8</div>
   <div id="pr-9"></div>
   <div id="pr-10"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS code

```
#wrapper 
{
  background-color: #fe8181;
  width: 300px;
  height: 510px;
  padding: 5px;
} 
#pr-1, #pr-2, #pr-3, #pr-4, #pr-5, #pr-6, #pr-7, #pr-8, #pr-9, #pr-10 
{
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 72px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/atulbnar/85zujvud/2/)

```
var limit = 5,
    amount = 5,
    lower_bound = 1,
    upper_bound = 10,
    unique_random_numbers = [];

if (amount > limit) limit = amount; //Infinite loop if you want more unique
                                    //Natural numbers than existemt in a
                                    // given range
while (unique_random_numbers.length < limit) {
    var random_number = Math.round(Math.random()*(upper_bound - lower_bound) + lower_bound);
    if (unique_random_numbers.indexOf(random_number) == -1) { 
        // Yay! new random number
        unique_random_numbers.push( random_number );
    }
}

var urllist=["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/Eenbruinigherfstblad.jpg","http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/57/Canadian_maple_leaf_2.jpg","http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Pear_Leaf.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7.jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg"];
//alert(unique_random_numbers);

for(var i = 0; i < unique_random_numbers.length; i++) {
    var a="<img width='45px' height='45px' id='"+(i+1)+"' src='"+urllist[unique_random_numbers[i]]+"' alt='image"+(unique_random_numbers[i])+"'/>";

  //  alert(a);

    $("#pr-"+unique_random_numbers[i]).html("");
    $("#pr-"+unique_random_numbers[i]).append(""+a);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using google logo image as example, you can change it to everything you want.
This is my solution:

```
<html>
<style>
    #wrapper 
    {
        background-color: #fe8181;
        width: 300px;
        height: 510px;
        padding: 5px;
    } 
    #pr-1, #pr-2, #pr-3, #pr-4, #pr-5, #pr-6, #pr-7, #pr-8, #pr-9, #pr-10
    {
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        height: 70px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        width: 72px;   
    }
</style>
<script language="javascript">
    var nos=new Array();
    function setImage()
    {
        var i=0,duplicate,max=5;
        while (i<max)
        {
            no=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            duplicate=false;
            for (j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
            if (nos[j]==no)
            {
                duplicate=true;
                break;
            }
            }
            if (duplicate==false)
            {
                i++;
                nos[j]=no;
            }
        }
        for (x in nos)
        {
            var div=document.getElementById("pr-"+nos[x]);
            div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML+"<img src='https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/logo_2x.png'>";
        }
    }
</script>
<body onload="setImage()">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="pr-1">1</div>     
<div id="pr-2">2</div>
<div id="pr-3">3</div>
<div id="pr-4">4</div>
<div id="pr-5">5</div>
    <div id="pr-6">6</div> 
    <div id="pr-7">7</div>
    <div id="pr-8">8</div>
    <div id="pr-9">9</div>
    <div id="pr-10">10</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much really , actually I'm stuck here from last days so i was feel very tired now this will help me so thanx bro...

Comment: Hi, can you plz suggest me if I take 5 different  images instead of same one . and  images shouldn'd  show together.... on every refresh but I'm unable do this so plz help out plz....

Comment: are these 5 images used every time?
are these 5 images shown in random sequence?

Comment: yes i am using only 5 images and yes i want those images in random sequences also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. I am not sure. Try it.

```
 //your image coolection array.
 var array = [{
        'src':'shape.jpeg'},
        {'src':'WodRob.png'},
        {'your image'},
        {'your image'}
    ];

//function to randomize array images.

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
//This will randomize the array on page refresh.
window.addEvemtListner('load',shuffle,false);
```